# Python: NameError: global name 'sortList' is not defined (During Recursion)

Tags: python, recursion

In the line (`l1 = sortList(head)`) for recursion, I get `NameError: global name 'sortList' is not defined`. 
Could anyone point out where I did wrong?

```
class Solution:
    # @param head, a ListNode
    # @return a ListNode

    def sortList(self, head):
        if head == None or head.next == None:
            return head

        slow = head
        fast = head

        while fast != None and fast.next != None:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
        fast = slow
        slow = slow.next
        fast.next = None
        l1 = sortList(head)
        l2 = sortList(slow)
        l = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2)
        return l
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've edited your code a bit - usually displaying a more minimal coding example (not the entire code, but just the relevant part) helps with the readability of the question.

Comment: It's also generally a good practice to accept the answer that answered your question.

Comment: Should I accept an answer by voting up or other method? Since I just entered Stackoverflow and my reputation hasn't reached 15, I could not vote up currently. I will definitely do so after I can. Thanks again.

Comment: There's a green V mark under the voting. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sortList` is a method of `Solution`, and doesn't exist independently.
Use:

```
self.sortList(head)
```

and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Change `l1 = sortList(head)` to `l1 = self.sortList(head)`, and `l2 = sortList(slow)` to `l2 = self.sortList(slow)`. `sortList` is defined in the `Solution` class and does not exist globally, that's why you need `self` to refer to the current `Solution` object.

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported any function named `sortList`, so there only exists a `sortList` that can be called on a `Solution` object.

Use `self.sortList`.  `self` is a variable used in python to refer to the current object.  Much like `this` in other languages.